# Layer reordering when scrolling fast

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, parallax

I have a layout that uses coordinator layout and a parallax scrolling image. Everything works the way I want when I scroll fairly slowly, but if I scroll fast or flick the screen to scroll then the image appears over the top of the title bar. I can then scroll back up and it will emerge from under the image and back on top again.

I've made a screen recording of what I mean which you should be able to view here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByPvcmldlZW-MFNUczRKZ0RGUTA/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the xml for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="app.com.example.android.bulletpoints.ui.DetailActivityFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_photo_height">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="@dimen/bulletpoint_elevation"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/detail_bar_title_top"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/detail_title_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_bar_subtitle_bottom"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/detail_subtitle_text_size" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bulletpoint_block_bottom"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/bulletpoint_elevation"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_1"
                        layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                    <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_2"
                        layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                    <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_3"
                        layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                    <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_4"
                        layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                    <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_5"
                        layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/ad_fab" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is anyone able to see where I've went wrong in my layout? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit: I had missed off the top level of the xml file so I've added it back in.*

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of moving things about but I've solved it so I thought I'd post the solution in case anyone else had a similar issue.

It came down to me thinking about the grouping incorrectly. I'm not sure why it would scroll the bar below the image but I think it has something to do with the NestedScrollView (*if anyone has insight on why this is please comment*).

To fix this I brought the bar up into the CollapsingToolbarLayout and put it inside a FrameLayout underneath the Imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="app.com.example.android.bulletpoints.ui.DetailActivityFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_photo_height">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/title_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/bulletpoint_elevation"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detail_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/detail_bar_title_top"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/detail_title_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detail_subtitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_bar_subtitle_bottom"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/detail_bar_text_margin"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/detail_subtitle_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bulletpoint_block_bottom"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bulletpoint_margin"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:elevation="@dimen/bulletpoint_elevation"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_1"
                    layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_2"
                    layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_3"
                    layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_4"
                    layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

                <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/bulletpoint_5"
                    layout="@layout/bulletpoint_item" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/ad_fab" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```